# How to select adjacent table in this CSS case?

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
    <!-- h1 with a span -->
    <h1> 
        <span>...</span> 
    </h1>
    <table>
        ...

    <!-- h1 without a span -->
    <h1>...</h1>
    <table>
        ...
```

How I can select the table that comes immediately after the `<h1>` that surrounds a `<span>`? I tried `h1 span + table` so that table is using the adjacent operator. However, it doesn't work. It's probably because table is being shown as adjacent to the `<span>` and not the `<h1>`. Any hints?

Comment: Try to adapt [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014958/7914637) for your case.

Answer (score 1):

As you are open to JavaScript solution, here's what I've done.

```js
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
  var elm = elms[i];
  
  if(!(elm.getElementsByTagName('span').length > 0))
    elm.className = "select-next-table";
}
```

```css
.select-next-table + table {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Don't select the next table</span></h1>
<table></table>

<h1>Select the next table</h1>
<table></table>
```

What am doing here is fetching all `h1` tags and looping them. Later, I try to search `span` inside the `h1` tag, if I don't get any, then I append a `class` to the `h1` element, and later, I use `.select-next-table + table` to select the tables which are adjacent to `h1` tags, and the `h1` doesn't have any `span` tags.

---

You can definitely select the table which is rendered after `h1` using

```
h1 + table
```

But you cannot check whether the `h1` contains a `span` element because once you go inside the `h1` tag, you cannot select the parent again. Hence, for such things, you might have to use JavaScript.

Comment: @Grateful You can click on the tick besides my answer to mark it as correct if it was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is checking for a table which is the first sibling after a span element inside an h1. I don't think you can select a table based on the span.

But you can add a class to the h1 and do 
`h1.class + table` Or maybe use the nth-child selector `h1:nth-child(1) + table`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with not being able to change the html!

Comment: The nth-child() solution does not require you to change html.

Comment: I need a solution that would work even if the second table became the first one!

Comment: That will need a jQuery or JS solution then. jQuery has a .parent() and .next() function which would solve your issue. You might want to add the javascript and jQuery tags to your question  (provided you are using jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

The `h1 span + table` selects a table that is placed immediately after `<span>` within `<h1>` element. But you want to select a table that is placed after `<h1>`, thus you need to use `h1 + table` selector. 
The [`:has()`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#has-pseudo) pseudo-class could help you to apply the rule only if `<h1>` contains a `<span>` tag:

```
h1:has(span) + table
```

The trouble is the Selectors Level 4 is still not supported by any browser. But it makes possible to set special `class` attribute value for specified tables via jQuery.

```js
$("h1:has(span)+table").addClass("special");
```

```css
.special {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  <span>H1 with &lt;span&gt;</span>
</h1>
<table>
  <tr><td>special style</td></tr>
</table>
<h1>H1 without &lt;span&gt;</h1>
<table>
  <tr><td>common style</td></tr>
</table>
```